# Oracle JRE 1.8.201 Open FileDialog on Windows 10 Citrix "The element "hcmd.exe" to which the link refers has been changed or moved"

Tags: java, swing, citrix, filedialog

[image: open filedialog swing]Some days ago we noticed that when opening a FileDialog under Citrix Windows in Java Swing the following message appears a few times. We use since Java 1.8.201, I tried it with the last 1.8 JRE, same problem.

The following message appears:
The element "hcmd.exe" to which the link refers has been changed or moved.

If you click away the error message a few times the FileDialog opens.

If I run the test on my notebook with the same JRE under Windows 10 this error message does not appear. As a hint, I have admin rights with my user on the notebook, on Citrix of course not.

Does anyone have any idea what this is due to?

Comment: Maybe u can check few things like "is your JDK/JRE properly installed?  Do you have proper permissions to the user?" Is your citrix blocking anything?

Comment: looks like this problem occurs: 
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8213583

the question is then, how to avoid that the broken link dialog is shown on citrix.
the link is not really broken. the link to the default "MyDocuments" folder in windows is a symlink to a networkdrive. but after clicking the windows broken link messages away the "My Documents" folder is shown in the file dialog.